# Passing allocatable arrays of size 'selected_int_kind(16)' using MPI

Tags: arrays, parallel-processing, fortran, mpi, subroutine

I am writing a code using Fortran90 in which I divide the job and each processors calls a subroutine which in turn returns an array of very large size (10^10).

For this I define that no. as

```
integer,parameter::my_type_int = selected_int_kind(16)
integer(kind=my_type_int)::n
```

then in root I define,

```
call mpi_type_create_f90_integer(16,type_int,err)
call mpi_type_commit(type_int,err)
```

I use `allocate' to allocate arrays in both all the processors and also subroutine and receive or send data as follows,

```
call mpi_send(n,1,type_int,id,send_data_tag,mpi_comm_world,err)
```

and array is send as follows,

```
call mpi_send(array,n,mpi_real8,root_process,return_data_tag,mpi_comm_world,err)
```

The code works perfectly fine till 10^7, but it gives following error for n 10^8 and above,

```
mpirun noticed that process rank 0 with PID 6053 on node *clustername* exited on signal 9 (Killed).
```

I am confused, since I don't change anything in the code and it works fine for smaller number and breaks down for larger. Please help.

Comment: How much memory do you have on the node? I guess you exceed that memory and the process is killed by the O/S. Do you check the `stat`us of he allocation? BTW: Both integers of kind `selected_int_kind(16)` and floats of kind `mpi_real8` have eight bytes on my machine, so arrays of length 10^8 would result into ~750MB each.

Comment: free -m gives 124525 MB is free so I think it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: It could be related to the `shmmax` kernel parameter which should be increased.

Comment: I increased that parameter to 4GB  - 1 byte but it doesn’t help.

Comment: @AnthonyScemama - Do you suspect increasing it more or error is with something else ?  Thanks.

Comment: The most robust and portable solution would be to send your array in fixed sized chunks of 10^6 elements. But try to increase the shmmax value even more to see if it's going to work.